# Launch default email and calendars on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

I know how to launch an activity given its package name, but for things like email and calendars, people usually have one of four or five proprietary or downloaded apps that they'll use. If I want a button to take the user to their default calendar or email, is there a way to do that nicely?

When a user goes to open a website, they're given a choice, chrome/browser/whatever, or if you've chosen a default, it just goes to that. Is there a way to do that with opening the user's default email/calendar application?

I know I could just have a bunch of intents for the most popular apps in try/catch blocks and hope that it opens up one the user uses, but that seems horribly ugly. Like a startActivity(EMAIL_INBOX) or intent(VIEW_CALENDAR) or something like that that takes care of it for you without the actual package name?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make Intents with the action `ACTION_MAIN` and category `CATEGORY_APP_CALENDAR` or `CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL` as appropriate.

Setting the action to ACTION_MAIN launches the app as though the user selected it from Home, and setting the category will limit their options to apps that provide that category. See the Standard Categories section of the [Intent class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more options.

For example:

```
Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
calIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALENDAR);
```

You can also use intents for specific actions, such the following to launch an email app with the action of sending an email:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Comment: Gave it a try and it worked, thanks a bunch :) One more question though, it makes the user select which app they want every time even if they hit the "Always use this app" button. Do you know how I can make it save the default/use the default if the user has selected one before?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. makeMainSelectorActivity() will force the selection dialog. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Without that, will it still pull the selection dialog up if the user hasn't chosen a default?

Comment: If the user has not selected a default, yes, it will show the dialog.